# actionPerformed cannot resolved type

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

when i try to call a method from actionPerformed lets say "text1.setText("asdasdasd");" (text1 object already created in constructor of TestBookShelf) it says me cannot resolved type .but it works in constructor.i'm kinda newbie but shouldn't all crap from TestBookShelf class be available to actionPerformed method?
i'm not allowed to post photo as i have only 6 reps
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pasting the code here would have been better.

Comment: sorry but my code is a mess.at first i tried it but indents make problems ,errors dont go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is `text1` is in fact local to the constructor.
So in your constructor you are doing:

```
public ClassConstructor()
{
  JTextField text = new JTextField() ;
}
```

If that's true, `text1` must be declared as an instance variable, then would it be resolved.
Like so:

```
public class ClassConstructor
{
   JTextField text ;
}
```

Comment: yes its created in constructor but in tutorials i watched it wasnt a problem

Comment: sorry for taking time.i found it and it seems like all you sad is true.it shouldnt be local.thanks a lot

Comment: Sure np, if you wish you can accept the answer. Anyways, good luck.